# Watch_dogs gang hideouts don't appear

Tags: watch-dogs

Ok, so i find the civilian with the gang hideout, hack him, it goes through the conversation like always, but no blue thingy appears...Nothing appears at all!!! The items of interest, crimes, convoys and stuff like that appear, but gang hideouts just WON'T... (P.s. I have liberated the whole map) Thanks in advance

Comment: When hacking civilians this only unlocks the mission, it doesn't start it automatically - on PS4 you press down on the d-pad to set a waypoint to the start of the mission. Not sure if that helps you?

Comment: No, i mean it doesn't even give me the option to press down (I have xbox360).

Comment: "find the civilian with the gang hideout" How are you doing that? In my game I just get a popup that says a new gang hideout is available when I run around and hack people.  I don't think there are specific phone calls/texts that you hack to get the gang hideouts.

Comment: There are. Basically they are conversations by messages.

Comment: Ah I just found one this weekend, most of the I found by remote profiling it seems.

Comment: I guess the side missions (gang hideout, contracts) only unlock after you advance in the main campaign. How far did you played?

Comment: the hideouts unlock after you have played through a certain ammount of main story, before that you cant do them. Alot of the side objectives only open later into the game, like the criminal investigation and the human traffic side missions.

Comment: You need to get to a waypoint. Press q on the waypoint to start it and then the hideout appears on the map

Answer (score 1):

After you have completed all gang hideouts, no more will appear. To get access to more gang hideouts, you must reset all side missions in the options menu, which will result in the loss of *all* side missions, not just gang hideouts, but not main missions.

Comment: This is horrible. I thought the game had quest generation as it's usual in todays games